# Extract number at end of string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

Probably over analysing this a little bit but how would stackoverflow suggest is the best way to return an integer that is contained at the end of a string.

Thus far I have considered using a simple loop, LINQ and regex but I'm curious what approaches I'll get from the community. Obviously this isn't a hard problem to solve but could have allot of variance in the solutions.

So to be more specific, how would you create a function to return an arbitrarily long integer/long that is appended at the end of an arbitrarily long string?

```
CPR123 => 123
ABCDEF123456 => 123456
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
\d+$

// RegexOptions.RightToLeft – is optional, but will increase performance
var result = Regex.Match(input, @"\d+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value;
```

or one-liner without regex:

```
var result = input[^input.Reverse().TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).Count()..];
```

or more efficient way:

```
int numberOfDigitsAtEnd = 0;
for (var i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(input[i]))
    {
        break;
    }

    numberOfDigitsAtEnd++;
}
        
var result = input[^numberOfDigitsAtEnd..];
```

Answer (score 30):

Obligatory LINQ one-liner

```
var input = "ABCD1234";
var result = string.Concat(input.ToArray().Reverse().TakeWhile(char.IsNumber).Reverse());
```

Comment: I think its great one from all answers. I was looking for this. Thanks!

Comment: But `IsNumber` will return true not only for 0-9 ASCII.

Comment: .ToArray() seems to be redundant

Answer (score 12):

Regex pattern like `\d+$` is a bit expensive since, by default, a string is parsed from left to right. Once the regex engine finds `1` in `12abc34`, it goes on to match `2`, and when it encounters `a`, the match is failed, next position is tried, and so on.

However, in .NET regex, there is a `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` modifier. It makes the regex engine parse the string from right to left and you may get matches that are known to be closer to the end much quicker.

```
var result = Regex.Match("000AB22CD1234", @"\d+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
if (result.Success) 
{ 
    Console.Write(result.Value);
}  // => 1234
```

See the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/QmUb88).

Answer (score 4):

Regex would be the easiest, as far as my experience.

```
Regex ex = new Regex(@"(\d+)$")
```

This should match it. Just wrap that in a function.

Comment: The parentheses in the regex are pointless though ;) (and even incur overhead, which is what the OP wanted to avoid)

Answer (score 1):

```
[^0-9]+([0-9]+)
```

should do it I think

Comment: What if there are integers before the one at the end of the string? What if there are no non-digit characters before the integer at the end of the string?

Comment: That' not what he asked for, his examples were for letters then numbers.  Anyway, as I said, Kirill's answer is better because it's simpler & deals with both those situations anyway

Comment: Hm okay. I read "arbitrarily long string" as "arbitrary string". Also "arbitrariy long" includes 0-length I guess.

Comment: It does, but in this case I don't think that's what he meant, I would normally check that externally to a Regex anyway

Answer (score 1):

Is it always in the format LettersNumbers?

In that case, this would work:

```
Regex _cellAddressRegex = new Regex(@"(?<Column>[a-z]+)(?<Row>[0-9]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var rowm = Convert.ToInt32(parts.Groups["Row"]);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the `Compiled` option.  You're paying a substantial upfront cost to compile the regex to MSIL, when as far as you know it's only gong to be used once, and it's so simple it probably won't benefit from the optimization anyway.

Comment: Indeed. I took that from a codebase of mine where it made sense, but for one-time it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Quick function to increment the number at the end of a string and return the updated string.
Example "STR0232" --f(x)--> "STR0233"

```
public static string IncrementTrailingNumber(String Input)
{
 string RtrnStr = "";

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input))
   {
      var result = Regex.Match(Input, @"\d+$",  RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value;
      int Increment = 0;
      if (result.Length>0)
      try
      { 
        Increment = int.Parse(result);
        Increment++;
      }
      catch(Exception expn)
      { }
      RtrnStr = Input.Substring(0,Input.Length-result.Length) + Increment.ToString($"D{result.Length}");
    }
    return RtrnStr;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I allowed to go crazy with this?

```
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

static string GetNum(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (input[i] < 48 || input[i] > 57)
            break;

        sb.Append(input[i]);
    }

    return String.Concat(sb.ToString().ToCharArray().Reverse());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop should probably beat any other solution in its simplicity and efficiency. And final returned string can be just copied once without usage of Stack, StringBuilder, string.Concat or other more complex string supporting functions.

```cs
string GetNumberFromEnd(string text)
{
    int i = text.Length - 1;
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        if (!char.IsNumber(text[i])) break;
        i--;
    }
    return text.Substring(i + 1);
}
```

Or it can be even returned back directly as int type:

```cs
bool GetIntFromEnd(string text, out int number)
{
    int i = text.Length - 1;
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        if (!char.IsNumber(text[i])) break;
        i--;
    }
    return int.TryParse(text.Substring(i + 1), out number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using RegEx that can be hard to understand, or Linq and array manipulation that can be slow, a simple loop in an extension method can be used.

It can be used for `long` or `int` or `ulong` or `uint` or other while adapting the `+` and `-` check.

It can be adapted to parse `float` and `double` or `decimal` too.

This method can also be written as a `Parse` to have exceptions.

**Implementation**

```
static public class StringHelper
{
  static public bool TryParseEndAsLong(this string str, out long result)
  {
    result = 0;
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) )
      return false;
    int index = str.Length - 1;
    for ( ; index >= 0; index-- )
    {
      char c = str[index];
      bool stop = c == '+' || c == '-';
      if ( !stop && !char.IsDigit(c) )
      {
        index++;
        break;
      }
      if ( stop )
        break;
    }
    return index <= 0 ? long.TryParse(str, out result)
                      : long.TryParse(str.Substring(index), out result);
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
test(null);
test("");
test("Test");
test("100");
test("-100");
test("100-200");
test("100 - 200");
test("Test 100");
test("Test100");
test("Test+100");
test("Test-100");
test("11111111111111111111");

Action<string> test = str =>
{
  if ( str.TryParseEndAsLong(out var value) )
    Console.WriteLine($"\"{str}\" => {value}");
  else
    Console.WriteLine($"\"{str}\" has not a long at the end");
};
```

**Output**

```
"" has not a long at the end
"" has not a long at the end
"Test" has not a long at the end
"100" => 100
"-100" => -100
"100-200" => -200
"100 - 200" => 200
"Test 100" => 100
"Test100" => 100
"Test+100" => 100
"Test-100" => -100
"11111111111111111111" has not a long at the end
```